# Existing Encryption and Validation method in Machine Key of IIS suddenly stops working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, .net-2.0

My application is hosted on IIS and it is previously working on SHA 1 and Auto Encryption and Validation method but suddenly it stops working on one server The same application is synced on other servers also but it works fine there. It starts going to stuck in redirections. In Event log it start giving data as **Unable to validate data** Later after R & D and trial and error method we came to know that the Application is working after changing machine key encryption and validation algorithm.

Event Log details.

Unable to validate data.
at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean signData) at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo) at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType) at System.Web.UI.Page.EncryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.FormatWebResourceUrl(String assemblyName, String resourceName, Int64 assemblyDate, Boolean htmlEncoded) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrlInternal(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, Boolean htmlEncoded) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrl(Type type, String resourceName, Boolean htmlEncoded) at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Type type, String resourceName) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterValidatorCommonScript() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Later after changing Encryption and validation method it starts giving Session timeout issue and in Event log getting **Forms authentication error**.

Event code: 4005
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.
Event time: 04/09/2023 4:45:38 PM
Event time (UTC): 04/09/2023 11:15:38 AM
Event ID: d84f9a41a0a1404e97a3fe7568ce0943
Event sequence: 2142
Event occurrence: 53
Event detail code: 50202

Later after changing Encryption and validation method it starts giving Session timeout issue and in Event log getting **Forms authentication error**.

Event code: 4005
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.
Event time: 04/09/2023 4:45:38 PM
Event time (UTC): 04/09/2023 11:15:38 AM
Event ID: d84f9a41a0a1404e97a3fe7568ce0943
Event sequence: 2142
Event occurrence: 53
Event detail code: 50202

Comment: There can be multiple possible reason the SHA-1 algorithm stope working, like the latest browsers now days does not support SHA-1, some iis server config changes, some code or dependency issue or the security policy on the server have been updated. May I know which iis version and algorithm right now you are using? What is the machine key setting? If possible could you share your web.config file by modifying your question.  What is the time-out value you have set for authentication and session?  Make sure that the server's clock is set correctly and matches the current date and time.

Comment: please enable iis failed request tracing and track if is there any 401 or not. Could you please check which TLS version is enabled on the server?